# Argument of type .. is not assignable to parameter of type .. in Typescript and unit test

Tags: javascript, typescript, highcharts, types, jasmine

I am trying to write a unit test for a custom method I wrote for Highcharts.

For my test, I need to create a `Highcharts.Point` object to pass into my custom utility method. Outside of the test, the `Point` object is created automatically when the chart is rendered, but for my test, I need to create a custom one with my own parameters.

My custom Point object called `PointObjectExtended` is an extension of [Highcharts.Point](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point), where `dataLabel` are the dimensions of the value labels on a point, and `shapeArgs` are the dimensions of the rectangle (basically the individual chart).

These are the type definitions:

```
export interface PointObjectExtended extends Highcharts.PointObject {
  dataLabel: DataLabel
  shapeArgs: ShapeArguments
}

export interface DataLabel {
  width: number
  height: number
  hide (): void
}

export interface ShapeArguments {
  width: number
  height: number
}
```

In my test, I have something of the following:

```
    const point = {
      shapeArgs: { width: 20, height: 20 },
      dataLabel: { width: 20, height: 20, hide: jasmine.createSpy('hide spy') }
    }
    hide(point)
  })
```

And this is the method implementation:

```
function hide (point: PointObjectExtended) {
  ..
  const shape = point.shapeArgs
  const label = point.dataLabel
  ..
}
```

The error I am getting when I try to pass in my `point` object into `hide()` is the following:

```
Argument of type '{ shapeArgs: { width: number; height: number; }; dataLabel: { width: number; height: number; hide...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PointObjectExtended'.
  Property 'category' is missing in type '{ shapeArgs: { width: number; height: number; }; dataLabel: { width: number; height: number; hide...'.
```

It seems to want me to declare the rest of the `Highcharts.Point object`. I don't think that's the right way to approach it, but I'm not sure what else I can do.

So my question is - how do I create a `PointObjectExtended` that I can pass into my unit test method?

One alternative is that for my method, I can set the `point` type to `any` and it would accept my fake point object in the test, but I don't want to use `any`, obviously.

```
function hide (point: any) {
  ..
  const shape = point.shapeArgs
  const label = point.dataLabel
  ..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new interface that does not extend the highchart point:

```
export interface PointObjectExtension {
  dataLabel: DataLabel
  shapeArgs: ShapeArguments
}

type PointObjectExtended = Highcharts.PointObject & PointObjectExtension;
```

So you can just do this in your function:

```
function hide(point: PointObjectExtension) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: @theGreenCabbage doesnt matter.

Comment: I figured out a better solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things, first, declare `point` as a `Partial`.

In the test, you have to declare a [Partial](https://netbasal.com/getting-to-know-the-partial-type-in-typescript-ecfcfbc87cb6) of `PointObjectExtended` and then cast the input to it.

```
  it('my nice test', function () {
    const point: Partial<PointObjectExtended> = {
      shapeArgs: { width: 20, height: 20 },
      dataLabel: { width: 26, height: 26 }
    }
    hide(point as PointObjectExtended)
    expect(hideSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()

  })
```

Comment: No, unsafe typecasting is an ugly and unsafe way to do this.